# How to mock the time for Later.JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, laterjs

I am using Later.JS for a automatic function call every first day of the month. For testing I need to mock the time to check if Later.JS and my code does the right things. Can some one help me how I can mock this past time.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What library do you use for unit testing? I like **Jest** because is very intuitive.
It has function *mock* documented [here](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/es6-class-mocks.html#calling-jestmock-jest-docs-en-jest-objecthtml-jestmockmodulename-factory-options-with-the-module-factory-parameter).

> jest.mock(path, moduleFactory) takes a module factory argument. A module factory is a function that returns the mock.

And usage:

`jest.mock('laterJS', () => () => ({format: () => '2018–01–30T12:34:56+00:00'}));`

Check also **jest.spyOn** documented [here](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/jest-object#jestspyonobject-methodname).

Last, but not least, there is **sinonJS** and its **stubs**, great tool for mocking functions and libraries and using your own implementation of function for testing purpose like returning hard-coded timestamp. [Here it is](https://sinonjs.org/releases/latest/stubs/).

**EDIT: After editing question I understood what OP want to achieve**

Alright, by unclear question I thought you were interesting in testing your code, now I'm aware you want to test both: laterJS schedule and your code.

Basically, all crones / schedulers are created for running code / tasks every some period of time. Under the hood, in very simplified way, scheduler is all the time checking if any of schedule conditions are met. If yes - do something. To achieve it you have mock **clock** to make laterJS to think that's a time to run his job.

I have no experience with laterJS, I have some with node-cron, but the idea is exactly the same. [Check some of their test suites](https://github.com/kelektiv/node-cron/tree/master/tests) to realise what approach is proper one.